# Kubernetes Service pointing to External Resource

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

We have an existing website, lets say `example.com`, which is a CNAME for `where.my.server.really.is.com`.

We're now developing new services using Kubernetes. Our first service `/login` is ready to be deployed. Using a mock HTML server I've been able to deploy two pods with seperate services that map to `example.com` and `example.com/login`.

What I would like to do is get rid of my mock HTML server, and provide a service inside of the cluster, that points to our full website outside of the server. Then I can change the DNS for `example.com` to point to our kubernetes cluster and people will still get the main site from `where.my.server.really.is.com`.

We are using Traefik for ingress, and these are the changes I've made to the config for the website:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: where.my.server.really.is.com

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: wordpress
    servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wordpress
          servicePort: 80
```

Unfortunately, when I visit `example.com`, rather than getting `where.my.server.really.is.com`, I get a 503 with the body "Service Unavailable". `example.com/login` works as expected

What have I missed?

Comment: Are the pods behind the service running ok? Try executing kubectl describe wordpress to see if the endpoints property contains the pods ip's. Which version of traefik are you using?

Comment: any news @DanielM?

Comment: @fiunchinho My current solution is using nginx as a light weight proxy. Your solution is neater, but I haven't tried it yet. I'll get back to you when I get the chance (sorry for the delay).

Answer (score 1):

Following [traefik documentation on using `ExternalName`](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubernetes.md#forwarding-to-externalnames)

> When specifying an ExternalName, Træfik will forward requests to the given host accordingly and use HTTPS when the Service port matches 443.
>
> This still requires setting up a proper port mapping on the Service from the Ingress port to the (external) Service port.

I believe you are missing the `ports` configuration of the Service. Something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: where.my.server.really.is.com
```

You can see [a full example in the docs](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubernetes.md#disable-per-ingress).

Comment: Unfortunately I now get a `Internal Server Error`. I'm not entirely sure if thats in k8s or the external service as there's no info in the header and nothing in Kibana (at least, nothing after I fixed a silly namespace error). I'm trying to do this over 443 if that makes a differnce. I've changed port name and number.